# Reading file line by line in dart

Tags: dart, dart-io

I'm trying to process large text files in a language Dart. The files have a size over 100 MB.

I tried `readAsLines` and `readAsLinesSync` methods of `dart:io` library. Every time I run out of memory: `Exhausted heap space`.

Is there a way to read a file line by line or byte by byte as in other languages​​?

Answer (score 26):

This should read the file in chunks:

```dart
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:convert';

main() {
  var path = ...;
  new File(path)
    .openRead()
    .map(utf8.decode)
    .transform(new LineSplitter())
    .forEach((l) => print('line: $l'));
}
```

There isn't much documentation about this yet. Perhaps file a bug asking for more docs.

Answer (score 17):

In the latest verion of dart the UTF8.decoder is now utf8.decoder:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:convert';

main() {
  var path = ...;
  File(path)
    .openRead()
    .transform(utf8.decoder)
    .transform(LineSplitter())
    .forEach((l) => print('line: $l'));
}
```

Comment: Downvoted because you should have edited the previous answer.

Comment: I didn't even know you could edit someone else's answer. Is there some etiquette to just updating someelse's answer?

Comment: Upvoted because the etiquette is generally to not modify code in other people's answers, though modifying other content is usually fine. However, this could have just been a comment below the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the comment and up vote. As a user of stack overflow I would actually  prefer a complete answer (however we arrive at that) as it's too easy to miss notes in the comments section.

Comment: I just posted my own answer, but then I realized that it was the same as yours so I deleted it. In addition to changing `UTF8` to `utf8`, you also replaced the map with another transform. I didn't notice that at first. That map was causing an exception in my code. Could you add an explanation for why you removed map? What does transform mean? (By the way, if you add @Suragch in your comment, I'll get notified when you reply.)

Comment: @suragch The map is used to do translation on the input from one object to another. So you a reading a text file, you do the utf8 transform to convert from bytes (which is what openRead returns, then the second transforms breaks the characters (well in dart there are actually single character strings) to into lines. You could then do a map to transform the lines into say an integer if you knew that the file your reading had a single number on each line.

Comment: Why did you remove the map from your answer that Greg Lowe's answer uses?

Comment: Doesn't work "Error: Unsupported operation: _Namespace"

Comment: @EightRice look at this article. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54861467/unsupported-operation-namespace-while-using-dart-io-on-web. Essentially you are using dart:io in a web app which isn't allowed.