# Unsupported operation: _Namespace while using dart io on web

Tags: web, io, dart

```
I am trying to use dart-io to read and write file. I am getting below exception.
Uncaught Error: Unsupported operation: _Namespace
    at Object.dart.throw (dart_sdk.js:4537)
    at Function.get _namespacePointer [as _namespacePointer] (dart_sdk.js:49364)
    at Function._namespacePointer (dart_sdk.js:47224)
    at Function._dispatchWithNamespace (dart_sdk.js:47227)
    at io._File.new.open (dart_sdk.js:47342)
    at new io._FileStreamConsumer.new (dart_sdk.js:47186)
    at io._File.new.openWrite (dart_sdk.js:47468)
    at refresh (main.dart:15)
    at refresh.next (<anonymous>)
    at runBody (dart_sdk.js:22264)
    at Object.async.async (dart_sdk.js:22292)
    at main.refresh (main.dart:13)
    at Object.dart._checkAndCall (dart_sdk.js:4731)
    at Object.dart.dcall (dart_sdk.js:4736)
```

Code I used
    final output = io.File('output.txt').openWrite();
    output.write(output_data);

```
Could you please help me in fixing it.
Or any other way to read and write files using dart in a web application.
```

Comment: `dart:io` can not be used in web projects. `dart:html` has some limited file API (limited to what the browser allows). Dart in the browser can not do anything the browser does not provide.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer if it is unsupported on web why in this lib mentioned as supported
https://pub.dev/packages/image

Comment: @MohammadHadi the package supports several platforms ( Dart: native, js;
Flutter: Android, iOS, web) and on Dart native and Flutter `dart:io` is allowed, just not in the browser, because the browser doesn't allow direct disk access and other stuff provided by `dart:io`.

Answer (score 33):

`dart:io` can not be used in web projects. `dart:html` has some limited file API (limited to what the browser allows). Dart in the browser can not do anything the browser does not provide.

(Not sure why Günter didn't put this as an answer...)

Answer (score 22):

```
if (kIsWeb) {
  image = Image.network(pickedFile.path);
} else {
  image = Image.file(File(pickedFile.path));
}
```

The answer is in the documentation
https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker

Comment: In particular, it's written in this part of the documentation https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker_for_web#usage

Answer (score 5):

use https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker library.

in dart file :-

```
import 'dart:io';
```

for pick the image use following code :-

```
_imgFromGallery() async {
   final temp = (await ImagePicker().
                 getImage(source:ImageSource.camera,imageQuality: 
                 80));
   imageForSendToAPI = await temp.readAsBytes();
   setState(() {});
  }
```

This method will take image from desktop.

here imageForSendToAPI will give you uint8list,which you can pass to API.

for showing the selected file use :

```
Image.memory(imageForSendToAPI)
```

for sending to API don't use multipart, just pass like below:-

```
data = {
"profile_image":imageForsendToAPI.toString();
}
```